# How to programmatically use or connect multiple C# applications?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm about to embark on a project to automate a manual process that involves many different desktop applications.  I'm wondering if there is any way to expose interfaces that already exist and use them in my application.  Most of the manual tasks just involve filling in a form in an existing application and pressing a button.  I'm not sure if this will be relevant to the solution or not, but the tasks sometimes take many hours to run.

Because I'll only be filling in existing forms and there's not really any need to change the existing apps, I'd prefer not to have to do lots of work with the existing applications.  If something like this seems like a good solution though, please let me know.

So, my main question is, what would be the best way to automate this process?  Should I import the existing applications as libraries?  Is there a way to fill in another program's WPF or Windows Forms interface programmatically?

Comment: you should try [autoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're looking for [Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx), or a tool such as [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/) or [Test Complete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools). More videos on Coded UI Tests available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You usually have a possibility to record a scenario for your Windows Forms or WPF application (or even write the code manually), and later run/replay it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can either fill in textboxes inte the existion application using a UI test automation tool or you can implement communication in the applications.

For UI test automation tools, see the other answers.

For communications frameworks, you can use one of these:

- [Windows Communication Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)
- [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/)

Comment: What do WCF or ServiceStack have to do with the question?

Comment: The question is: "**How to programmatically** use or **connect multiple C# applications?**" and in the text it sais "I'm wondering if there is any way to expose interfaces that already exist and use them in my application". WCF and ServiceStack are appropriate for this, in particular if not all applications run on the same computer.

Comment: The question might be misleading by using the words "interfaces" and "connect", but basically boils down to the requirement of populating the (visual) interface of an existing WindowsForms or WPF application programmatically. How exactly can you achieve this goal by using WCF?

Comment: Well, I don't necessarily want to complete the project by filling in the visual interfaces, but if it's a good, maintainable solution, then I'm all for it.  I mainly stated that because all of the other projects are complete and implemented, so I'm looking for a way to tie them together.

Comment: Yakimych: The question sais "... use or connect ..." and for the "connect" part WCF and ServiceStack are both appropriate. If OP only meant to ask about "use", then I simply misunderstood.

Comment: @RyanE - well, in that case it depends a lot on how you've architectured your WinForms of WPF apps. For example, if you use `MVVM` and all your visual controls are bound to properties/commands of your `ViewModel` object, it would be enough to add a reference to the assembly containing your ViewModel class, change the properties and invoke commands on it without creating the GUI components. However, if you have your logic in codebehind files (e.g. code in `button_click` events etc.), then it might be really tricky to make those calls without any Coded UI tools.

Comment: @Yakimych Alright, that makes sense.  I'm thinking with the way the projects are architected, the first approach will hopefully be possible.  If there is a lot of logic in the codebehind, is it possible to create the GUI component and fill it in when the project is included as an assembly?  From C# preferably, rather than an outside tool.  I'm thinking along the lines of `var myForm = new MyGuiElement();  myForm.display = false;  myForm.txtSearch = "hello world"; myForm.button.click();`

Comment: @Ryan E: If you have business logic code in your UI layer and don't want to refactor your code, then it's a good (viable) approach to consume UI components like you suggest.

Comment: @RyanE - again, it depends. I can see a bunch of potential problems with this approach though. For example, if you want to invoke button clicks as you describe, you have to make a bunch of controls or methods (such as `button_click` events) `public` (when they should be `private`), breaking some principles along the way. Alternatively, keep them private and access them via reflection, which is going to be hacky in a different way. I'd say the best way is to separate the GUI from the logic by using patterns such as MVVM or MVP. If that's not possible, the coded UI approach is an alternative.

Comment: Alright, thanks!  After exploring some of the apps, it looks like the business logic is luckily all separated from the GUI.  I think I'm going to include them as libraries and go from there.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is a free scripting language was designed for this.  That will let you throw values into an existing UI without making any changes to the application.  There are a bunch of UI testing tools out there that could fulfill your needs as well (IE TestComplete), but most aren't free.